# How to close a PDA account when the structure has been changed

Tags: anchor, pda

I tried to close a PDA account that has changed in structure, but ran into:

"Error: memory allocation failed, out of memory"

Comment: If you're failing to allocate memory during the program, you might be using too many accounts without zero-copy serialization or too much heap-allocated state in general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to specify `close = destination` in the anchor macro but it did not work.

So I ended up copying the code from here to close the account and passing in `UncheckedAccount`:

https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/latest/src/anchor_lang/common.rs.html